# Given text. Break it down into words. Through streams

Tags: regex, stream

Given text. Break it down into words. Through streams: Leave only those words that start with 'a', convert them all to lowercase, collect all words into a collection. Print this collection (each word on a new line).
Maybe there are other solutions?

```
public class Task_1 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String text = "A new report on the. state of American youth says!!!" +
            " teenagers, are very concerned about the direction their nation is taking. ";
    Stream.of(text.split("[^A-Za-zА-Яа-я]+"))
            .map(String::toLowerCase)
            .filter(n -> n.startsWith("a"))
            .sorted()
            .collect(Collectors.toList())
            .forEach(System.out::println);
}
}
```

Comment: Please let know if my answer below helps.

Answer (score 1):

You may match all words starting with `a` using `(?i)\ba\p{L}*\b` regex, put the matches into a list of strings turning them to lower case, then sort the list and print the items:

```
String text = "A new report on the. state of American youth says!!!" +
        " teenagers, are very concerned about the direction their nation is taking. ";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?i)\\ba\\p{L}*\\b");
Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
List<String> res = new ArrayList<>();
while(m.find()) {
    res.add(m.group().toLowerCase()); // Add to list turning to lower case
}
Collections.sort(res);     // Sort
for (String s: res)
    System.out.println(s); // Print
```

See the [Java demo online](https://ideone.com/hDPX0a).

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yfCCP0/1). Details:

- `(?i)` - case insensitive mode on
- `\b` - a word boundary
- `a` - a `a` letter
- `\p{L}*` - 0 or more letters
- `\b`  - a word boundary.